# Interface Freezing after server start

Tags: java, interface, server, client

im creating a client/server program. Clients need to connect to a server that is connected to a interface and every 5 min clients send a String that will be showed in the server's inteface.
This is the Server Interface code:

```
public class MainServer implements ActionListener {

public  static JFrame f_principale;
JButton avvio_server;
JButton ferma_server;
public static JLabel risultato;
JButton richiesta;
Server server;

public static JTextArea ritorni;

public MainServer(){

    UI_LOADER();

}

public void BUTTON_LOADER(){

    avvio_server = new JButton("Avvia");
    ferma_server = new JButton("Ferma");
    richiesta = new JButton("Richiedi");

    avvio_server.addActionListener(this);
    ferma_server.addActionListener(this);
    richiesta.addActionListener(this);

}

public void TEXT_LOADER(){

    risultato = new JLabel();
    risultato.setText("prova");
    ritorni = new JTextArea();

}

public void WINDOW_LOADER(){

    f_principale = new JFrame("Centro Meteorologica");
    f_principale.setSize(800, 600);
    f_principale.setVisible(true);
    f_principale.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f_principale.setBackground(Color.gray);

    f_principale.add(avvio_server);
    f_principale.add(ferma_server);
    f_principale.add(richiesta);
    f_principale.add(ritorni);
    f_principale.add(risultato);

    avvio_server.setBounds(100, 400, 200, 100);
    ferma_server.setBounds(500, 400, 200, 100);
    richiesta.setBounds(350, 400, 100, 50);
    ritorni.setBounds(100, 50, 600, 300);
    risultato.setBounds(300, 530, 200, 50);



}

public void UI_LOADER(){

    BUTTON_LOADER();
    TEXT_LOADER();
    WINDOW_LOADER();


}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MainServer m1 = new MainServer();


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
    if(button.getText() == "Avvia"){

        System.out.print("Server avviato");
        Thread server = new Server(); 
        System.out.print("Server avviato");
        server.run();
        System.out.print("Server avviato");

      }       

    if(button.getText() == "Ferma"){

        try {
            server.closeServer();
        } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

    if(button.getText() == "Richiedi"){


      }

}
```

And this is the Server code:

```
public class Server extends Thread{

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
int clientPort;
ArrayList clients = new ArrayList();


public void run(){

    Socket client;

    try {

        MainServer.ritorni.setText("Server Aperto");
        serverSocket= new ServerSocket(4500);
        System.out.println("Server Aperto");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        MainServer.risultato.setText("Errore nel aprire il server");
    }


    while(true){

        client = null;

        try {
            client=serverSocket.accept();
            MainServer.risultato.setText("Dispositivo collegato");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            MainServer.risultato.setText("Errore nel collegare il dispositivo");
        }
        clients.add(client);
        Thread t=new Thread(new AscoltoDispositivo(client));
        t.start();

        }
}


public void closeServer() throws IOException{

    serverSocket.close();

}

public void broadcastMessage(BufferedReader is, DataOutputStream os, Socket client) throws IOException{
    for(Iterator all=clients.iterator();all.hasNext();){
        Socket cl=(Socket)all.next();
        sendMessage(cl);

    }

}

private void sendMessage(Socket cl) throws IOException{
        new DataOutputStream(cl.getOutputStream()).writeBytes("ASKRESPONSE");
}


}

class AscoltoDispositivo implements Runnable{
    DataOutputStream os;
    BufferedReader is;
    Socket client;
    static String tempReceived = null;

    public AscoltoDispositivo(Socket client){

        this.client=client;

        try{

            is= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            os= new DataOutputStream (client.getOutputStream());

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            while(true){

                try {
                    tempReceived = is.readLine();
                    MainServer.ritorni.append(tempReceived);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
}
```

my only problem is that the interface get freezed after i click the start button.

Comment: The `while(true)` isn't a good practice. Also, try adding a timer in this loop (`Thread.sleep()` for example)

Comment: The problem is that the interface seems connected to the Server in some way but i set it to be a thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your Server running on the UI thread:

```
if(button.getText() == "Avvia"){

    System.out.print("Server avviato");
    Thread server = new Server(); 
    System.out.print("Server avviato");
    server.start(); // <- not run()
    System.out.print("Server avviato");
  }
```

Comment: It worked, thank you :)